# Android Alarms not working on some phones

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm, notificationmanager

I have a really serious issue with my android application.

My app contains reminders: AlarmManager+NotificationManager. Some users reported bugs, such as reminders stops working after a few days. The phones are Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, and OnePlus One (both Lollypop). Alarms are restored on boot, so this is not the issue, and one user says if he starts the app, at least once a day, the bug doesn't happen.

I also have a strange problem with a test device: Honor 6 (Kitkat)
When I install the apk from Android Studio, the reminders work just fine, but when I isntall the same apk from Google Play, the reminders don't work.

Do you have any idea what could cause these bugs?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, So far your problem is a little vague, could you narrow it down by sharing some code snippets? Also if you have two questions, you should  ask them separately to ensure you get the best help possible!

Comment: This might help you, particularly the comments by Ruppesh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037720/android-alarmmanager-stops-when-activity-die